# golang не захватывает сетевые пакеты

Tags: golang, pcap

Есть устройство которое работает в режиме моста, трафик идет п канальному(2) уровню. Использую функцию `source := gopacket.NewPacketSource(handler, handler.LinkType())` и не происходит захват трафика.
При этом команда `tcpdump -i br0 -S -A tcp` захватывает трафик.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Покажите полный код, как вы читаете пакеты